# How do I input data from java GUI into MS Access using UCanAccess

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm new to using UCanAccess and Microsoft Access as a database for java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.*;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.*;

public class Memo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    Connection cn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement s = null;

    public Memo() {

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(246, 0, 178, 50);
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enter bill amount: $");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 0, 237, 50);
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter water usage amount(l): ");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 11));
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        label.setBounds(10, 49, 237, 50);
        getContentPane().add(label);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(246, 49, 178, 50);
        getContentPane().add(textField_1);

        JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnSubmit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\decx\\Desktop\\Db.accdb");
                    String sql = "insert into db ('ID', 'WaterUsage', 'Bill') + values ('1', '12', '12')";
                    s = cn.createStatement();
                    s.executeUpdate(sql);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        btnSubmit.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 11));
        btnSubmit.setBounds(272, 131, 141, 35);
        getContentPane().add(btnSubmit);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Memo qMemo = new Memo();
        qMemo.setSize(500, 350);
        qMemo.setVisible(true);
        qMemo.setTitle("Tips & Tricks");
        qMemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        qMemo.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

I need to get the code to send data when the submit button is clicked. This is a school project where I have to allow users to enter water usage and bill (water utility bill), so I can display it later.

I have ran the code previously and but errors like "unexpected token" or "user has no privilege or object not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some notes :

1. You get this error (`unexpected token`) because the names of columns and table should not be between two quotes `''`
2. The `+` operator is not allow in that position of query
3. Also, only the Strings can be between two quotes not the ints, make sure the type of ID for example is a String, if not you have to remove the two quotes
4. Read about [Prepared Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid syntax error and to prevent SQL Injection

Look at :

```
String sql="insert into db ('ID', 'WaterUsage', 'Bill') + values ('1', '12', '12')";
//(1)-----------------------^--^--^----------^--^----^  ^         ^ ^
//(2)___________________________________________________|         | |
//(3)_____________________________________________________________| |
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

That helped me a lot and with the help of my friends i completed my code, for anyone who might need this at any point, i'll be including my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.*;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.*;

public class Memo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;

Connection cn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement s = null;

public Memo() {

    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(246, 0, 178, 50);
    getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enter bill amount: $");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 11));
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 0, 237, 50);
    getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter water usage amount(l): ");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 11));
    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    label.setBounds(10, 49, 237, 50);
    getContentPane().add(label);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(246, 49, 178, 50);
    getContentPane().add(textField_1);


    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());

                textField.getText();
                textField_1.getText();


                Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\DECX\\Desktop\\Db.accdb");
                String sql = "insert into db (WaterUsage, Bill) values ('"+num+"', '"+num1+"')";
                s = cn.createStatement();
                s.executeUpdate(sql);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
    btnSubmit.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 11));
    btnSubmit.setBounds(272, 131, 141, 35);
    getContentPane().add(btnSubmit);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Memo qMemo = new Memo();
    qMemo.setSize(500, 350);
    qMemo.setVisible(true);
    qMemo.setTitle("Memo");
    qMemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    qMemo.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
}
```